# JavaFX TabPane,Tab.setContent() doesn't work

Tags: java, javafx

The problem is that i want to transfer an item between a `GridPane` and a `Tab`
so i am adding the item to the tab first.

Then i am adding the same item to the **GridPane**.Its works well until here.But then i want to add the item back to the tab and i am using

```
tab.setContent(item);
```

But it doesn't work.Neither the item is removed from the GridPane neither the item is added to the tab as content.Why is this happening??

> The **.java** file:

```
package pack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Starter extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new UI()));
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    /**
     * This class contains the graphical interface
     * 
     * @author Alexander
     *
     */
    public class UI extends BorderPane implements Initializable {

        @FXML
        private Tab tab;

        @FXML
        private Button item;

        @FXML
        private GridPane gridPane;

        @FXML
        private Button transferButton;

        boolean onGridPane = false;

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public UI() {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("UI.fxml"));
            loader.setController(this);
            loader.setRoot(this);

            try {
                loader.load();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
            System.out.println("Main Controller has been initialized....");

            transferButton.setOnAction(a -> {
                if (!onGridPane) {
                    gridPane.add(item, 0, 0);
                    onGridPane = true;
                    transferButton.setText("<-Move to Tab");
                } else {
                    tab.setContent(item);
                    onGridPane = false;
                    transferButton.setText("Move to GridPane->");
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

> And the **.fxml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<fx:root prefHeight="322.0" prefWidth="538.0" type="BorderPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <top>
      <TabPane prefHeight="141.0" prefWidth="538.0" style="-fx-border-color: red;" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <tabs>
          <Tab fx:id="tab" text="Tab">
               <content>
                  <Button fx:id="item" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Moving Item" />
               </content>
          </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </top>
   <bottom>
      <GridPane fx:id="gridPane" gridLinesVisible="true" style="-fx-border-color: red;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
      </GridPane>
   </bottom>
   <right>
      <Button fx:id="transferButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Move to GridPane-&gt;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font size="16.0" />
         </font></Button>
   </right>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
   </padding>
   <center>
      <Label prefHeight="82.0" prefWidth="340.0" style="-fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-font-size: 15;" text="Above is a [TabPane] and Below is a [GridPane]" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
</fx:root>
```

Comment: You can't put the same node in two different places in the scene graph.

Comment: @James_D I though adding the item into one layout it removes it from the other..Why it doesn't work?I want the item to be one time at GridPane and one time at Tab.

Comment: "adding the item into one layout it removes it from the other.." There is nowhere in the documentation that says that...

Comment: @James_D I am curious though why the the item from the Tab the first time  goes to GridPane.

Comment: The behavior is undefined. There is nothing you should expect to happen or not happen.

Comment: I've just looked at the source code and a **`Parent`** removes a child that is added from the old `Parent`. `Tab` doesn't extend `Parent` though. Furthermore there is also a property (`javafx.sg.warn`) that causes warning being printed to `System.err`, if a `Node` has to be removed from the old `Parent`, so it's in no way a good thing to let `Parent` do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodes cannot appear twice in the scene graph; adding a node that is already part of the scene graph to the scene graph again is explicitly forbidden by the API, so the behavior if you try to do so is undefined.

You need to remove the button from the scene graph before adding it elsewhere:

```
transferButton.setOnAction(a -> {
    if (!onGridPane) {
        tab.setContent(null);
        gridPane.add(item, 0, 0);
        onGridPane = true;
        transferButton.setText("<-Move to Tab");
    } else {
        gridPane.getChildren().remove(item);
        tab.setContent(item);
        onGridPane = false;
        transferButton.setText("Move to GridPane->");
    }
});
```